# Database design for bookmark system

Tags: database-design, schema, normalization, erd

I am creating a bookmark system where people can save their bookmarks. Each user has its own personal page with bookmarks. A bookmark should have atleast one tag and max five. Each user can create unlimited bookmarks / tags.

I created the following tables:

```
User
----
Id
Email


Bookmark
--------
Id
UserId
Title
Url


Tag
---
Id
UserId
Title
Description


TagBookmark
-----------
TagId
BookmarkId
```

Is this normalized? Or should I do this differently? Will this perform well with a million bookmarks?

I am also not sure if I should reuse already existing bookmarks / tags.

**Example 1:**

User1 and User2 both create the bookmark "http://google.com". Should I save this as one bookmark? Or save them for each user individually?

**Example 2:**

User1 and User2 both create the tag "search-engine". Should I save this as one tag? Or save them for each user individually?

If I do not reuse bookmarks and tags between users these tables may grow quite large.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Designing for maximum performance for an anticipated large user-base, I would suggest ensuring bookmarks and tags are not duplicated unnecessarily.  Using my suggested schema below, `http://google.com/` would become a single bookmark row.  Users who want a bookmark to Google would have a row in `UserBookmarksTags` referencing the Bookmark row and the associated tag row.

I would tend to abstract the UserID away from the Bookmarks table, and use a cross-reference table to determine which users have bookmarks, and what they've tagged each bookmark with.

Using SQL Server, I would do it like this:

```
USE tempdb;
GO
CREATE TABLE Users
(
    UserID INT NOT NULL 
        CONSTRAINT PK_Users
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
        IDENTITY(1,1)
    , UserName varchar(255)
);
CREATE TABLE Bookmarks
(
    BookmarkID INT NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT PK_Bookmarks
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
        IDENTITY(1,1)
    , BookmarkName varchar(255)
    , BookmarkURL varchar(255)
);
CREATE TABLE Tags
(
    TagID INT NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT PK_Tags
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
        IDENTITY(1,1)
    , TagName varchar(255)
);
```

If every entry in your system requires both a bookmark and a tag, you could use the following table for maximum performance:

```
CREATE TABLE UsersBookmarksTags
(
    UserID INT NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT FK_UsersBookmarksTags_UserID
        FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Users(UserID)
    , TagID INT NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT FK_UsersBookmarksTags_TagID
        FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Tags(TagID)
    , BookmarkID INT NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT FK_UsersBooksmarksTags_BookmarkID
        FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Bookmarks(BookmarkID)
    , CONSTRAINT PK_UsersBookmarksTags
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
        (UserID, TagID, BookmarkID)
);
```

The above version of the table `UsersBookmarksTags` allows you to quickly return a list of bookmarks for a specific user that matches any given tag, or all bookmarks for that user.

Alternately, you could create the cross reference table that allows null entries for both Tags and Bookmarks, as in:

```
CREATE TABLE UsersBookmarksTags
(
    UsersTagsBookmarksID INT NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT PK_UsersBookmarksTags
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
        IDENTITY(1,1)
    , UserID INT NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT FK_UserBookmarks_UserID
        FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Users(UserID)
    , TagID INT NULL
        CONSTRAINT FK_UserBookmarks_TagID
        FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Tags(TagID)
    , BookmarkID INT NULL
        CONSTRAINT FK_UserBooksmarks_BookmarkID
        FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Bookmarks(BookmarkID)
);
```

This allows rows that have a bookmark without a tag, and also allows tags to be associated to a user without a bookmark.

If there is a requirement to know all the tags a user has added, without those tags necessarily having an associated bookmark, I would consider adding another table for that purpose, as:

```
CREATE TABLE UserTags
(
    UserID INT NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT FK_UserTags_UserID
        FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Users(UserID)
    , TagID INT NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT FK_UserTags_TagID
        FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Tags(TagID)
    , CONSTRAINT PK_UserTags
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
        (UserID, TagID)
);
```

Comment: Could you describe why this schema is more preferable than mine? Perhaps performance? Thank you so far!

Comment: Bookmarks and tags in your schema cannot be shared among multiple users without duplicating data.  I thought your requirement was to have a single row for each Bookmark, and a single row for each Tag, that could be joined to multiple users.  I created a schema that provides the most de-duplicated data in a way that provides fast searching by User and Tag.

Comment: I have one short question. When a user deletes a bookmark or tag, the UserTags / UserBookmarkTags will be updated. Should I also delete bookmarks or tags in the Bookmarks / Tags table if nobody uses them?

Comment: I'd probably leave them in the list.  Maybe once a month run a cleanup routine just to ensure the table doesn't get too out of hand.

Answer (score 1):

```
User //Might be useful to have a seperate ID for the relationship between the user data
----
Id
UserId
Email


Bookmark
--------
Id
Title
Url


BookmarkUser //Lookup Table
------------
Id
UserId
Bookmark.Id


TagList //You don't need to associate users with tags
---
Id
Title


TagBookmark
-----------
Tags.TagId
Bookmarks.Id


BookmarkView //Suggestion. Aggregates data, will make queries easier
------------
User.UserId
Bookmark.Id
Tags.TagID
```

Answer (score 0):

This design looks perfect to me.  I would keep bookmarks and tags distinct for each user, as you have it.  This will save you from the complexity of which user has which tags for a shared bookmark, or which bookmarks for a shared tag.  It's not like they'll be taking up a lot of space.

Your future self thanks you for not creating fields "Tag1", "Tag2", "Tag3", etc.!